# Match() with regex on JS returning NULL

Tags: javascript, regex

How to set a string variable in JS to a matched regex from another String ?
When I search using Sublime or Notepad it works, yet it does not work with JS.

```
var str = " 261   OSCAR BARRAGAN ALFARO EL 17-05-14 $2832.00";
var result = str.match('\s[0-9]{3}\s');
console.log(result);

OUTPUT : NULL
```

yet the expected output should be ' 261 ' , Any Ideas ?

Comment: BTW the output to that regex should be ' 261 '.

Comment: yes I fixed it in the question, my bad

Comment: Btw `[0-9]` can be simplified to `\d`

Comment: regex are not strings in javascript but RegExp objects, you need to enclose them between slashes (and not quotes), or to use an explicit object creation, see mdn doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression isn't a regular expression, it's a string. The delimiter for regular expression literals is `/`, not `'`:

```
var result = str.match(/\s[0-9]{3}\s/);
// Note ---------------^------------^
```

Note that the result will be `" 261 "`, not `"261"` (note the spaces). If you don't want the spaces, you can use a capture group:

```
var match = str.match(/\s([0-9]{3})\s/);
// Note -----------------^--------^
var result = match ? match[1] : undefined;
```

Live example:

```js
var str = " 261   OSCAR BARRAGAN ALFARO EL 17-05-14 $2832.00";
var match = str.match(/\s([0-9]{3})\s/);
var result = match ? match[1] : undefined;
snippet.log(result);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use that as regex. When you wrap it inside `''` it will act as string

```
var str = " 261   OSCAR BARRAGAN ALFARO EL 17-05-14 $2832.00";
var result = str.match(/\s[0-9]{3}\s/);
console.log(result[0]); 
//result will contain an array of matches and in that index 0 will give you 261
```

Answer (score 0):

You RegEx pattern is not right. Use

```
var result = str.match(/\s[0-9]{3}\s/);
```